# HttpContext.HttpRequest.files empty

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using html form below and on my local computer trying to upload file to ASP.NET HTTPModule and read files using `HttpContext.HttpRequest.files` Unfortunately `HttpContext.HttpRequest.files` do not contain any files. Where is the problem?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form  action="http://localhost:2006/MyASPNETModule" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
       Please choose file from your computer  <br />
    <input type="file">  
    <button id="btnConvert" type="submit">
        Convert</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you missing runat="server" in form?

Comment: No, this is simple html form, not asp.net app. I am submitting it to ASP.NET module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your file input a name:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```